# Need Custom Dead-Letter Queue using MSMQ not WCF

Tags: msmq

I'm using MSMQ on Server 2012 with the `System.Messaging` class, not WCF. When my message is sent to my Private queue I set the `TimeToBeReceived` property of the message to 1 minute. Should this time expire I need this message to be removed from this queue and placed in a secondary queue. To accomplish this I am setting `UseDeadLetterQueue = true` which causes the message to be moved to the system DLQ. The problem is of course that this message can get mixed in with messages from other queues.

I have two questions:

1. Not using WCF, is there a way to specify a custom DLQ?
2. Is there another way to handle this time expiry and sending the message to another queue that does not involve the DLQ?